# Subsequence of Sequence of Random Variables and Convergence in Probability

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. real random variables, with $\mathbb E(X_1)=0$, $\operatorname{var}(X_1)=1$. Let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$.

Prove that for any subsequence $(n_k)_{k\geq 1}$, $$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{S_{n_{k}}}{\sqrt{n_k}}=+\infty\right)=1$$

And that

$$\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n\geq 1}$$

does not converge in probability.

Comment: Note that, by definition of lim sup, the statement over all subsequences is equivalent to the statement over the whole sequence : $\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}=+\infty\right)=1$

Comment: Excellent, so as Davide noted in the hint below we use Kolmogorov's 0-1 law to show the statement over the whole sequence, and then by the definition of lim sup the the statement for any subsequence follows?

Comment: Yes, this is it, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** use Kolmogorov's $0-1$ law.